# Coroutine support in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Does Typescript support Coroutines (ECMAScript 6)? I've tried something like:

**function*(){}**

However, typescript won't compile.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [not supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3605) yet, but will arrive in [TypeScript 1.6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap).

Specifically:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2873